# Oracle conditional update query

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have one requirement as shown below :

Suppose we have EMP table with 5 rows having deptno = 20  --Here i will get deptno i.e.20 from input paramter

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB       MGR   HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7566    JONES   MANAGER   7839  04/02/1981  2975    -   20 
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST   7566  12/09/1982  3000    -   20 
7902    FORD    ANALYST   7566  12/03/1981  3000    -   20 
7369    SMITH   CLERK     7902  12/17/1980  800     -   20 
7876    ADAMS   CLERK     7788  01/12/1983  1100    -   20
```

Now I want to write one UPDATE query in procedure which will update EMP Table 
set JOB = 'MANAGER' where empno in (7788,7902);  -- Here empno i.e. 7788 and 7902 i will get from input parameter

My update query Should update JOB = 'MANAGER' for 2 rows having deptno = 20 
and for rest of 3 rows i want to update will Null values.

So that final output will be as shown below :

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB       MGR   HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7566    JONES             7839  04/02/1981  2975    -   20 
7788    SCOTT   MANAGER   7566  12/09/1982  3000    -   20 
7902    FORD    MANAGER   7566  12/03/1981  3000    -   20 
7369    SMITH             7902  12/17/1980  800     -   20 
7876    ADAMS             7788  01/12/1983  1100    -   20
```

So what will be the best way to write this query

Comment: You say you'll get empno as an input parameter. What format does your input parameter follow? Is it a CSV list? A PL/SQL table? IOW, how do you accept multiple empno values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE emp
   SET job = (CASE empno
                 WHEN 7788
                 THEN 'MANAGER'
                 WHEN 7902
                 THEN 'MANAGER'
                 ELSE NULL
               END)
 WHERE deptno = 20;
```

Or

```
UPDATE emp
   SET job = (CASE
                 WHEN empno IN (7788, 7902)
                 THEN 'MANAGER'
                 ELSE NULL
               END)
 WHERE deptno = 20;
```

Hope this is what you are after...

EDIT: After your comments about the input coming from a number table type something like this should work:

```
CREATE TYPE number_tab
AS TABLE OF NUMBER
/
```

> Type Created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE upd_emp (
   p_deptno    IN emp.deptno%TYPE,
   p_empno_tab IN number_tab
)
IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE emp e
      SET e.job = (SELECT (CASE 
                             WHEN t.column_value IS NULL
                             THEN NULL
                             ELSE 'MANAGER'
                            END)
                     FROM TABLE(p_empno_tab) t
                    WHERE t.column_value(+) = e.empno)
    WHERE deptno = p_deptno;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      ...Exception handling code
END upd_emp;
/
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention one thing in example that I am getting my input parameter in the form of collection. So in this scenario, I can't write simple case statement. So I have to use some loop instead of directly using case when statement which is making problem

Comment: OK, what sort of collection is your input parameter?

Comment: Its user declared Number Table type

Comment: OK, see the new edit to my answer. You'll have to play about with it for your exact scenario but it should be pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I'd prefer to solve this with two update statements

```
UPDATE emp SET job = null
WHERE deptno = 20
AND empno NOT IN (7788, 7902);

UPDATE emp SET job = 'MANAGER'
WHERE deptno = 20
AND empno IN (7788, 7902);
```

If you want to put it into one update, you can go like this:

```
UPDATE emp SET job = DECODE(empno, 7788, 'MANAGER', 7902, 'MANAGER', null)
WHERE deptno = 20;
```

Comment: Tom Kyte recommends the use of CASE over decode - "Decode is somewhat obscure -- CASE is very very clear.  
Things that are easy to do in decode are easy to do in CASE, things that are hard or near 
impossible to do with decode are easy to do in CASE.  CASE, logic wise, wins hands down."

Comment: Yupp, `case` is preferable over then `decode`, I agree with that. My point is, however, that in some case, unless you have a performance consideration, both are discouraged. Especially when your SQL is generated by middleware app, it is more clear to make this with two separate updates.

Comment: I'd still prefer to do it in one update, less work to be done, less context switches, one statement to maintain etc.